# Using PHP / Mysql in Xamarin for Login and Redirect to another XAML

Tags: c#, php, mysql, authentication, xamarin

I just started to use Xamarin. Now i have learnt how to create Cross Platform Apps. But now i have a Worry. I want to get input from the input Box as this

Here is what my XAML looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Qasimapp.Page1"
             BackgroundColor="#fff">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image Source="slim_logo.png" x:Name="logom" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
            <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#ff77D065"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And use this to connect to a database using WebAPI or something like a normal PHP API and redirect to another form such as the Dashboard. here is what my PHP looks like

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ('Cannot Connect to Database'.mysqli_error());

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['userID']);
$passwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['passwd']);
$designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['designation']);


$query = "SELECT * FROM evmsdbusers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$passwd' and designation='$designation'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

if($designation == 'User')
    {
        saveLoginLogs();
    }
    else if($designation =='Security')
    {
        saveLoginLogs();
    }
}

?>
```

Now i have uploaded it to a server on here http://32.125.23.120/login.php for instance and i want to use it to login using XAML cross platform

How can I achieve something like this? How can it Authenticate and then redirect to the main Page i want it to? I am very new to something like this and all my search prove abortive .

Comment: you should create a Rest API first, read [this article](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html) about creating Rest APIs in php. Then you should connect your app to your backend trough the API.

Comment: Use an API to connect your app and backend. Read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest) to learn how to Consume a RESTful Web Service.